# interface is not receiving string from mikroC Pro

Tags: c#, mikroc

I want to send string from mikroC pro to PC using C# interface.
my code is:

```
void main()
{
    while (1) 
    {
        if (UART1_Data_Ready())
        {
            UART1_Write_Text("mikroC");
            Delay_ms(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

but when is received in C#, it return as whole string first time, then it returns pieces of it, like it first sends 'm' then 'ikroC'. etc
where as my C# code is:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(serialPort1.ReadExisting().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `UART1_Write_Text`

Comment: C# doesn't support `while(1)` as C, you have to use `while(true)`.

Comment: this code is written in mikroc

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN document says : The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received. Use the **SerialPort.BytesToRead** property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer.
For more information refer to this [MSDN Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)